# Why redirect to next activity before flash screen finish its animation in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, splash-screen

I have created an Android application. recently I added a SplashScreen for it. but if I run application without redirecting to the main application, Animation is playing normally. but when it is redirected to main activity splash screen cannot see at all. it is launching main activity directly. can someone exmplain the reason for it ?

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        StartAnimations();


/* If comment these lines animations works fine, */
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SpalshScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();

    }


private void StartAnimations() {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);


}
```

I can avoid this behavior by adding a thread  as below.

```
Thread timer = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SpalshScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
```

But I want to know the reason for this behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use AnimationListener, Implement below listener with your animation and once animation is completed you can start new activity

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SpalshScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns For your kind information Mr Tim. We have posted the answer at the same time and it is coincidence. You should not download vote my answer. When I was writing my answer then your answer wasn't there.